# Using baseController inside Alloy widget

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

I would like to extend my controller within simple widget.

I've created two files:

- app/widgets/mywidget/controllers/base.js
- app/widgets/mywidget/controllers/index.js

I start mycontroller.js file with line: `exports.baseController = 'base';` and on Android it crashes with Exception: 

`/V8Exception(19693): Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:280: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: alloy/controllers//glass/parent`

Project tree looks like this:

```
app
├── README
├── alloy.js
├── assets
├── config.json
├── controllers
│   ├── base.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── view.js
├── lib
│   └── user.js
├── models
├── styles
│   ├── app.tss
│   └── index.tss
├── views
│   ├── index.xml
│   └── view.xml
└── widgets
    └── mywidget
        ├── controllers
        │   ├── base.js
        │   ├── index.js
        │   └── view.js
        ├── styles
        ├── views
        └── widget.json
```

index.js & view.js inside app/controller use base.js as baseController.
index.js & view.js inside app/widgets/mywidget/controllers use base.js inside same directory as their baseController. I don't try to extend baseController from app inside widget.

Comment: I really recommend reading through the Alloy docs, the concept of controllers and widgets is explained at http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets

Comment: I read that and my conclusion is that you can't use controller inheritance inside widget. Just to clear out: I don't want to extend my app base controller inside widget but have separate base controller as parent for all controllers created inside widget. I'll edit my question.